# Python write both commands and their output to a file

Tags: python, bash, markdown

Is there any way to write both commands and their output to an external file?

Let's say I have a script *outtest.py* :

```
import random
from statistics import median, mean

d = [random.random()**2 for _ in range(1000)]
d_mean = round(mean(d), 2)
print(f'mean: {d_mean}')
d_median = round(median(d), 2)
print(f'median: {d_median}')
```

Now if I want to capture its output only I know I can just do:

```
python3 outtest.py > outtest.txt
```

However, this will only give me an *outtest.txt* file with e.g.:

```
mean: 0.34
median: 0.27
```

**What I'm looking for is a way to get an output file like**:

```
import random
from statistics import median, mean

d = [random.random()**2 for _ in range(1000)]
d_mean = round(mean(d), 2)
print(f'mean: {d_mean}')
>> mean: 0.34
d_median = round(median(d), 2)
print(f'median: {d_median}')
>> median: 0.27
```

Or some other format (markdown, whatever). Essentially, something like *jupyter notebook* or *Rmarkdown* but with using standard *.py* files.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to write your python code into a file? If yes I think you need to have a separate file for your code and another code to capture from and write the output to a new file.

Comment: @M.R. yes I want to write code and the output it produces to a single file, in a way that shows which command produced which output, as in the example above. I've seen for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790352/how-to-output-both-command-and-output-of-the-command-to-both-console-and-log) for bash functions but I'm struggling to do it in python

Comment: One option would be to use something like `sys.settrace` to print lines of code out as they are executed (this would be the rough equivalent of `bash -x`). Below, in my answer, I show a different approach which prints each line of code exactly once as if it were pasted into a REPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script I just wrote which quite comprehensively captures printed output and prints it alongside the code, no matter how it's printed or how much is printed in one go. It uses the `ast` module to parse the Python source, executes the program one statement at a time (kind of as if it was fed to the REPL), then prints the output from each statement. Python 3.6+ (but easily modified for e.g. Python 2.x):

```py
import ast
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} <script.py> [args...]")
    exit(1)

# Replace stdout so we can mix program output and source code cleanly
real_stdout = sys.stdout
class FakeStdout:
    ''' A replacement for stdout that prefixes # to every line of output, so it can be mixed with code. '''
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.curline = ''

    def _writerow(self, row):
        self.file.write('# ')
        self.file.write(row)
        self.file.write('\n')

    def write(self, text):
        if not text:
            return
        rows = text.split('\n')
        self.curline += rows.pop(0)
        if not rows:
            return
        for row in rows:
            self._writerow(self.curline)
            self.curline = row

    def flush(self):
        if self.curline:
            self._writerow(self.curline)
            self.curline = ''

sys.stdout = FakeStdout(real_stdout)

class EndLineFinder(ast.NodeVisitor):
    ''' This class functions as a replacement for the somewhat unreliable end_lineno attribute.

    It simply finds the largest line number among all child nodes. '''

    def __init__(self):
        self.max_lineno = 0

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        if hasattr(node, 'lineno'):
            self.max_lineno = max(self.max_lineno, node.lineno)
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)

# Pretend the script was called directly
del sys.argv[0]

# We'll walk each statement of the file and execute it separately.
# This way, we can place the output for each statement right after the statement itself.
filename = sys.argv[0]
source = open(filename, 'r').read()
lines = source.split('\n')
module = ast.parse(source, filename)
env = {'__name__': '__main__'}

prevline = 0
endfinder = EndLineFinder()

for stmt in module.body:
    # note: end_lineno will be 1-indexed (but it's always used as an endpoint, so no off-by-one errors here)
    endfinder.visit(stmt)
    end_lineno = endfinder.max_lineno
    for line in range(prevline, end_lineno):
        print(lines[line], file=real_stdout)
    prevline = end_lineno
    # run a one-line "module" containing only this statement
    exec(compile(ast.Module([stmt]), filename, 'exec'), env)
    # flush any incomplete output (FakeStdout is "line-buffered")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Here's a test script:

```py
print(3); print(4)
print(5)

if 1:
    print(6)

x = 3
for i in range(6):
    print(x + i)

import sys
sys.stdout.write('I love Python')

import pprint
pprint.pprint({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, width=5)
```

and the result:

```py
print(3); print(4)
# 3
# 4
print(5)
# 5

if 1:
    print(6)
# 6

x = 3
for i in range(6):
    print(x + i)
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# 7
# 8

import sys
sys.stdout.write('I love Python')
# I love Python

import pprint
pprint.pprint({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, width=5)
# {'a': 'b',
#  'c': 'd'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the script and inspect its output. You'll have to make some assumptions though. The output is only from stdout, only from lines containing the string "print", and each print produces only one line of output. That being the case, an example command to run it:

```
> python writer.py script.py
```

And the script would look like this:

```
from sys import argv
from subprocess import run, PIPE

script = argv[1]
r = run('python ' + script, stdout=PIPE)
out = r.stdout.decode().split('\n')

with open(script, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
        if 'print' in line:
            f.write('>>> ' + out[i])
            i += 1
```

And the output:

```
import random
from statistics import median, mean

d = [random.random()**2 for _ in range(1000)]
d_mean = round(mean(d), 2)
print(f'mean: {d_mean}')
>>> mean: 0.33
d_median = round(median(d), 2)
print(f'median: {d_median}')
>>> median: 0.24
```

More complex cases with multiline output or other statements producing output, this won't work. I guess it would require some in depth introspection.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be similar to @Felix answer, but I'm trying to do it in a pythonic way.

Just grab the source code (`mycode`) and then execute it and capture the results, finally write them back to the output file.

Remember that I've used [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) to the demonstration for the solution and you shouldn't use it in a production environment.

I also used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906390/6700019) to capture stdout from `exec`.
    import mycode
    import inspect
    import sys
    from io import StringIO
    import contextlib

```
source_code = inspect.getsource(mycode)
output_file = "output.py"


@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
    old = sys.stdout
    if stdout is None:
        stdout = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = stdout
    yield stdout
    sys.stdout = old


# execute code
with stdoutIO() as s:
    exec(source_code)

# capture stdout
stdout = s.getvalue().splitlines()[::-1]

# write to file
with open(output_file, "w") as f:
    for line in source_code.splitlines():
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
        if 'print' in line:
            f.write(">> {}".format(stdout.pop()))
            f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign result to variable before print out and later on write those values to file

Here is example

```
import random
from statistics import median, mean

d = [random.random()**2 for _ in range(1000)]
d_mean = round(mean(d), 2)
foo = f'mean: {d_mean}'
print(foo)
d_median = round(median(d), 2)
bar = f'median: {d_median}'
print(bar)

# save to file
with open("outtest.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.write(foo + "\n")
    file.write(bar + "\n")
    file.close()
```

argument "a+" mean open file and append content to file instead of overwrite if file was exist.

Comment: This is not really what pieca asked for, this won't include the code in output.